# Change the nominations process for Best Of 2023

Tags: discussion, status-completed, best-of

As discussed [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62880550#62880550), Best Of 2022 has had a serious lack of nominations, with currently 4 of the 16 categories *still* uncontested.

So that this dosen't happen next year, I'd like to propose a change for Best Of 2023:

Open nominations about now instead of in January next year, but then open voting as usual at the start of 2024.

This will allow nominations to trickle in throughout the year, as and when people notice worthy posts. This way, we hopefully won't have such a problem with a lack of nominations, because people won't have to successfully remember and/or find good posts long after they were posted.

Comment: One concern I'd have with this is that people might forget about this, if nominations were open for the entire year. We've had trouble with people remembering long-term, ongoing events before, and I could see this happening, getting an early influx of nominations, then forgotten about by the summer

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing I think if you had a core of regular users making nomination comments for good posts semi-regularly, awareness would kind of seep into the community at large.  At minimum, the other regs would see these posts and be reminded.  Also the bar is low to improve on the current situation :)

Comment: We could have a quarterly chat event where we look for posts to nominate together

Comment: @Jonah Currently nominations don't go on the posts themselves, just in an answer on Meta, which isn't super visible. Are you proposing changing it so that nominations are also added as comments on the post itself? (I'd support that)

Comment: @RydwolfPrograms I was actually thinking the comment would link to the meta post, but I like your idea even better as its lower friction.  Could even introduce automatic meta post creation based on format… otoh, arguably the friction is a good

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Yes

With only minor and fixable problems, this has been done: see [Best of CGCC 2023 - Call for categories](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25541).